# Why class name can be referenced inside class even after it was redefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, es6-class

The following as you'd expect doesn't work:

```
let User = {
    foo() {
        User.prop = 1;
    }
};

let User2 = User;
User = null;

User2.foo();  // Cannot set property of null
console.log(User2.prop);
```

This works, though:

```
class User {
    static foo() {
        User.prop = 1;
    }
}

let User2 = User;
User = null;

User2.foo();
console.log(User2.prop);  // 1
```

Since functions and classes are objects, and in both cases I set a property for it, why is it that the results differ? Where is it getting `User` reference?

Comment: Notice that your first example doesn't use a static method on anything, it's more like code inside a class `constructor`. May I edit to clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My original code had a function which, once called, sets a property to itself (since it's an object). Why did you think it necessary to introduce a `User` object?

Comment: It's so that the way of calling (`User2.foo();`) is the same in both examples, and the difference is more pronounced. If you want to use a function, it would also be possible to write `let User = function() {}; User.foo = function() { User.prop = 1; };`. Feel free to edit or roll my change back - it's your question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to [named function expressions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr), `class`es are wrapped in an extra scope that contains an immutable binding with their name and value.

If we desugar the `class` syntax to ES5 faithfully, we'd get something like

```
let User = (() => {
    const User = function() {};
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
    User.foo = function() {
        User.prop = 1;
    };
    return User;
})();

let User2 = User;
User = null;

User2.foo();
console.log(User2.prop);  // 1
```

This inner `User` declaration is the one that the `foo` method is closing over. Overwriting the outer variable doesn't matter to it.

Comment: IMHO explanation should be given in term of the semantic of the given code without involve the semantic of underlying (js) level. At class level the point is that a static method can be called without need to instantiate the class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), that's why it gets "1", the rest is a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the declaration of a class, the name of that class is permanently bound. This is just one of the distinctions between old-school constructor-function classes and proper ES2015 classes. (Another important distinction that functions of a given name can be safely redeclared, but classes of the same name cannot.)

Answer (score -1):

In second example you get 1 because are referring to a static variable even it is inside a class that is not instantiated before use it. Removing the static and instantiating correctly it return 1 anyway:

```
class User {
    foo() {
        this.prop = 1;
    }
}

let User2 = new User();
User = null;

User2.foo();
console.log(">>" + User2.prop);  // 1
```

Note `User = null` is irrelevant.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about